# How to Hide API Keys In MERN Stack application?

Tags: reactjs, api-key, mern

I'm trying to add Google Maps into my MERN Stack Application. According to Some sources, I found out that adding .env file in create-react-app does not solve the purpose of hidding the API_Keys (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/). How can I store my API_KEYS in back-end (Node.js) and access it from react-app..
[Please find the below link, to check my file structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4tel.png)

Comment: Hi @Sruthi and welcome to Stack Overflow. 
Could you please explain further why you want to store the API_KEYS in backend? 
It would be helpful in giving you a solid advice.

Comment: From create-react-app's documentation, WARNING: Do not store any secrets (such as private API keys) in your React app! Environment variables are embedded into the build, meaning anyone can view them by inspecting your app's files. create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables So I want to store in backend and hide my API_KEYS. Hope this will help you understand by question better

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear.

Setting up custom environment variables in .env file, protect you from accidentally pushing API keys into your code whereas also allowing you to access them while working locally. You should never ever expose your API keys to the frontend.
Thus you store them in an .env file which is added to the .gitignore.

Generally, it is recommended to hit the API from backend where API keys are hidden.

Also checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52095890/should-i-make-3rd-party-api-calls-in-backend-or-frontend) for more info.